# Usage of the adverb "largely"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I am confused about the use of "largely", an adverb, in the following sentence I read in a newspaper today

> India has imposed a largely successful lockdown.

Here, the adverb "largely" should qualify the verb "imposed", but I am having a hard time grasping the usage here.

Comment: Actually, “largely” modifies the adjective “successful.” It means “mostly.” To call a lockdown “largely successful” is to say that the lockdown has succeeded for the most part, though it has not been 100% successful.

Answer (score 2):

Adverbs are words that modify verbs or other modifiers - which means they might modify adjectives or even other adverbs.

The main clue that *largely* is modifying *successful* is the article before it.  The things that can come between an article and a noun are adjectives and adverbs that modify those adjectives.

Adverbs can't reach back earlier in the sentence once an article appears until *after* the noun.